# Radio button values to be populated in the text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

All,

I have this set up.

When a user selects the check box, the radio buttons are enabled.

I am having problems when the user selects just 1 or 2 check boxes and changes the radio buttons eg from Met to Not Met etc. all the checked radio buttons are populated. I just want the radio button value + row id to be populated. So if 2 check boxes are checked and radio buttons are changed, only those two should show in the text area.

Also, there is an input field when Missing radio button is clicked and its value needs to be populated too.

With help from here, managed to work till here..

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Uv/43/)

```
$("input:radio").hover(function () {
$(this).prev('.r-title').show();
}, function () {
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
}
});

//Radio Buttons

$("input:radio").click(function () {
$(this).parent().parent().find('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
var totalRd = $('table').find('input:radio:checked').length;
var clicked = [];
$("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd); //Counts the radio buttons clicked
$(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').show();
$('table').find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
var newVal = ($(this).next('.m-notes:visible').length) ? this.value + "~" +     $(this).next('.m-notes:visible').val() : this.value;
    clicked.push(selectedId + "~" + newVal);
}); //checked
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
});

//Input Field for Missing Radio Button

$('.m-notes').keyup(function () {
var $self = $(this);
var clicked = [];
$('table').find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
    var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var newVal =  this.value + "~" + $(this).next('.m-notes').val();
    clicked.push(selectedId + "~" + newVal);
}); //checked
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
});

//CheckBox
var clicked=[];
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().find("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled',!this.checked);

$("#inputhere").val("");
$(".chkBx").each(function(){
if($(this).prop("checked")){
var txtVal =       $(this).parents("div").eq(1).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
        var idRowVal = $(this).parents("div").eq(1).attr("id");
        var textboxPrevValue = $("#inputhere").val();
        var textAndIdVal = textboxPrevValue +  idRowVal + "~ "+ txtVal+"|" ;
        $("#inputhere").val(textAndIdVal);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Could you maybe simplify your demo? Maybe show one row of inputs with only a couple of `radio`s with simpler/shorter/more-obvious `values`?

Comment: Hi! David, Thanks for your advice, I will remove the unessarcy radio buttons.